# Getting Undefined Variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, callback, node.js

UPDATED CODE: i, I'm new to Javascript programming and getting an undefined variable when trying to assign a new variable from a method.

I'm using node.js and creating a redis server using the redis-client in the "client variable".

```
var redis = require("redis");
var client = redis.createClient();

client.on("error", function (err) {
console.log("Error " + err); });

var numberPosts;

client.get("global:nextPostId", function(err, replies) {
  numberPosts = replies;
  console.log(numberPosts);
});

console.log(numberPosts);
```

When I call console.log inside the call back function it returns the proper value, however when I call the console.log outside of the callback function it returns "undefined". I'm trying to assign the value that is inside the callback function to the global variable numberPosts.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Matt

Comment: When var numberPosts = client.get("global:nextPostId",  redis.print); 
is executed it results in undefined.

Comment: You simply can't do that like this. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this will work:

```
client.get("global:nextPostId", function (err, reply) {
    console.log("Number of posts: " + reply.toString());
})
```

The AJAX call is asynchronous so it doesn't have return value.. instead you have to use callback function and only there you have the value returned by the server method.

Edit: to assign the return value to global variable, first declare global variable:

```
var _numOfPosts = "";
```

Then:

```
client.get("global:nextPostId", function (err, reply) {
     _numOfPosts = reply.toString());
})
```

However, the value won't be available until the AJAX call is finished so your original code can't work. There is not direct return value to store.

You can set timer to some reasonable response time, then have the code using the global variable in there.

Edit II: in order to call the method again once it's finished, have such code:

```
var _nextPostCallCount = 0;
function GetNextPost() {
   //debug
   console.log("GetNextPost called already " + _nextPostCallCount  + " times");

   //sanity check:
   if (_nextPostCallCount  > 1000) {
      console.log("too many times, aborting");
      return;
   }

   //invoke method:
   client.get("global:nextPostId", function(err, replies) {
      numberPosts = parseInt(replies.toString(), 10);
      console.log("num of replies #" + (_nextPostCallCount + 1) + ": " + numberPosts);

      //stop condition here.... for example if replies are 0
      if (!isNaN(numberPosts) && numberPosts > 0)
         GetNextPost();
   });

   //add to counter:
   _nextPostCallCount++;
}
GetNextPost();
```

This will call the method over and over until the result is 0 or you pass some hard coded limit to prevent endless loop.

Comment: That works and we've been able to get that to work. But the problem we have is when we try to assign the value "reply" into a global variable.

Comment: Show wizard: Thanks for your help on this one. Unfortunately it is still returning undefined when I try to access _numOfPosts outside of the callback function.

Comment: @Mat try `window.setTimeout(function() { alert("num: " + _numOfPosts); }, 3000);` this will show the alert after 3 seconds when the global variable should have value.

Comment: As I'm rereading this it looks like you are staying this may not be possible. Let me tell you what we've trying to achieve. We essentially just want to return the value of global:nextPostId into a variable, and then loop through each post id and spit out each post body into a websocket.

Comment: We're using node.js and are new to handling asynchronous data.

Comment: @Mat I *think* that I finally understand what you're after.. see my new edit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead to see errors:

```
var redis = require("redis"); 

client = redis.createClient(); 

client.on("error", function (err) {
console.log("Error " + err); });

//note the error logging
var numberPosts = client.get("global:nextPostId", function (error, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("async: " + error);
  } else {
    console.log("programming: " + response);
  }
});

console.log("is lotsa fun: " + numberPosts);
```

As Shadow Wizard has pointed out you are trying to use numberPosts before there is something in it, as client.get() hasn't returned anything.

Read this to get a handle on node.js flow:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/40366684/Nodejs-Controlling-Flow

Comment: This is exactly the same as what was originally posted, except that you've introduced a global variable ("client"), right?  Why would this make any difference?

Comment: That's not where were having the problem. Note the "," in the orignal code after require("redis"). We're specifically having the problem with the var numberPosts = client.get("global:nextPostId",  redis.print); That is resulting in undefined.

Comment: There is no error, he's trying to use the response before it arrive.

Comment: console.log"is lotsa fun: + numberPosts); still returns "undefined"

Comment: it's undefined for the reasons Shadow Wizard has said, you can't use it before it exists, the call outside the closure is "faster" than the client.get and so it has nothing yet...you need to wait until there is something returned from client.get before using it

Comment: JP: This makes lots of sense now. Thanks for clarifying. Let me tell you what we've trying to achieve as we're likely going about it in the wrong way. We essentially just want to return the value of global:nextPostId into a variable, and then loop through each post id and spit out each post body into a websocket

Comment: The other thing that doesn't make sense to me regarding the timer is that this is server side javascript code. Nothing is coming from the client, it's coming from the db.

Comment: @Mat this is true but the basic rules are still the same, among them the fact that asynchronous function can't have direct return value.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the the same issue when I applied the MVC framework.
To solve the problem, I employed the render function.

In the posts Model

```
exports.get = function(id,render) {
    client.incr('post:id:'+id, function(err, reply) {
    render(reply);
    });
};
```

In the posts Controller

```
exports.get = function(req, res) {
    posts.get('001', function (data){res.render('index',{post:data});});

};
```